# skipping characters with printf

Tags: c, console

I'm trying to write a program which would write on the console at a very specific position in the screen. Say for example from column 20 to column 39.
After each write, the line is "reset" thanks to the `\r` parameter. This ensures that the line remains static and only the specific fields are updated.

Problem is, i can instruct printf to write from column 0 to 19 without erasing the rest of the line, but it seems i'm not able to instruct printf to write from column 20 onwards without erasing in the process columns 0 to 19.

Is there a (standard) way to do this ? 
using something else than printf is possible.

[Edit] I've read there is a gotoxy() function in C which is available for windows apparently, and can be emulated in Linux using ncurses. Is there any problem with this function ?

Comment: `\r` does not mean *reset* but *carriage return*.

Comment: yes, thanks for the reminder. I know, it's just that in this context, `\r` serves this purpose.

Comment: What Operating System do you use? For UNIX-like there is the curses- or ncurses-library.

Comment: Primary target OS is windows. Linux comes afterwards. I would prefer to avoid using an external library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try printing as many backspaces (and spaces to clear old text) as needed to position the cursor.

No guarantee it works for you ... if it does: no guarantee it works on the other computer :)

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
  int i, k;
  time_t oldtime = time(0);
  if (oldtime == (time_t)-1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "time function does not work on this machine\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  while (time(0) == oldtime) /* void */;

  printf("fixed stuff: ");
  for (i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
    int val = pow(10, i) * i;
    printf("%d", val);
    fflush(stdout);
    oldtime = time(0);
    while (time(0) == oldtime) /* void */;
    if (i < 5) {
      for (k = 0; k < i + 1; k++) printf("\b \b"); // go back; erase; go back again
      fflush(stdout);
    } else {
      puts("");
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

*It works for me, on both Linux and Windows computers*

Comment: OK, this is the better work-around so far. It's not that easy though, since i would like to have several processes updating their fields on the same line. With the `\b` command, i can at least come up with a 2-fields line mechanism. But for 3 and more, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there's no standard way to do this because there's no console behavior standarization (eg Windows' console does not behave like Linux's)

Answer (score 1):

According to [ANSI documentation](http://bluesock.org/~willg/dev/ansi.html), you can use `"\033[1;20H"` to position the cursor.

It will move the cursor to the needed position. The values 1 and 20 are the row and the column, just change it to position correctly your print.

Or you can try with only `"\033[20C"` to move your cursor to column 20.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Cédric. Unfortunately, it did not work. I guess this could be because it needs ANSI.SYS driver loaded.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same trouble before. I used gotoxy() when I coded in TurboC++.

Check this out. Looks good.

http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/c/code/216326#

Answer (score 0):

Why Don't you just sprintf (myStr,.... and build the line in memory then output it in one go?
You could keep the fields you want from the previous update.

Comment: Several different processes are writing on the line. It's not a single program.

Answer (score 0):

Marc Rochkind wrote a realy good book which is the leading reference on the subject! [Advanced C Programming for Displays: Character Displays, Windows, and Keyboards for the Unix and Ms-DOS Operating Systems](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0130102407)